# I can't get vine.co to load on a WebView, not matter what useragent I send.

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I am making an app which needs to be able to browse to a few sites, one of those sites might be vine.co. Anyways, it loads almost every website just fine but when I go to test vine.co it just won't show anything. I made a webview example from scratch to try it and had the same issue. I've tried it on 4.3 and 4.4.

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
            wv.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    // settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    });
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("https://vine.co");
```

And here is the response I get, the page just looks blank.

```
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


  <title>Vine</title>

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/1035bae3.app.min.css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico">

  <!-- for more details visit: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin -->

  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script src="/assets/acb720d0.config.min.js"></script>

  <script src="/assets/e5147ec0.vendor.min.js"></script>

  <script src="/assets/3cabf7a5.app.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.APP_CONFIG = {"API_HOST": "https:\/\/api.vineapp.com", "CDN_HOST": "d3422saexnbpnl.cloudfront.net", "TWITTER_API_KEY": "PznIKCDSsllDCqWPooGSJg", "CLIENT_LOGGING": false, "CDN_PREFIX": "", "SECURE_HOSTNAME": "https:\/\/vine.co", "CDN_VERSION": "20140121"};
    window.PUSHSTATE_ENABLED = window.history && window.history.pushState;
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._gaq = window._gaq || [];
  window._gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34240974-1']);
  window._gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'vine.co']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <p class="browsehappy">
      You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
      <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a>
      to improve your experience.
    </p>
  <![endif]-->


  <script>
    window.App = require('appkit/app')["default"].create();
  </script>

</body></html>
```

What in the world am I doing wrong? it loads just fine on Chrome which I am hearing uses the same engine as WebView does on kitkat!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the culprit might have been not having `settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`.